# Exploring MCDRAM

Tags: memory, sdram, dram

I was going through the below link and found one peripheral named MCDRAM. If i am not wrong it looks like a Multichannel memory device which is integrated on same package. Can someone explain what exactly it is, where it can be used and what is the technology involved in it?

http://wccftech.com/intel-xeon-phi-knights-landing-features-integrated-memory-500-gbs-bandwidth-ddr4-memory-support-architecture-detailed/

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it is hybrid memory cube:  http://www.micron.com/products/hybrid-memory-cube

Just on package.  HMC has a high speed serdes controller interface, that connects to a stack of dram dies.   You can read more about it there.

HMC was my first guess and it's mentioned here: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8217/intels-knights-landing-coprocessor-detailed

[image]